# maximum length or constant

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I have a vector `v` that is created on-the-fly for each group within a data.table, for example like this:

```
x[,i[v[1:n]], by=.(group)]
```

The length of `v` is different for each group, so I cannot define `length(v)` outside of the data.table.

The constant `n` gives the highest element of `v` I am interested in. In cases where `n <= length(v)`, no problem  exists and I can query

```
v[1:n]
```

However, when `n>length(v)`, I call a non-existing index. Therefore, I need a function `f(n)` that I can use in `v[1:f(n)]` such that it returns

```
v[1:length(v)] if n>length(v)
v[1:n] if n<=length(v)
```

I could write an `ifelse(.)` into the index but this gets quite lengthy. I wonder whether there is a function that does this. In matlab, there is a variable `end` for the length of a vector. Writing a function myself is difficult because executing `v` outside of the data.table is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pmin` to do the check for the lengths between 'n' and 'v'.  If the 'n' is less than the `length` of 'v', it use 'n' and when it is greater than the length of 'v', it use 'v'

```
n1 <- pmin(n, length(v))
v[seq_len(n1)]
```

---

Regardng OP' issue within the `data.table`.

```
x[, {
      n1 <- pmin(n, length(v))
      i[v[seq_len(n1]]
      },
              by=.(group)]
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot evaluate `length(v)` outside of the data.table. The reason is that it is a `subcomponent(.)` of some graph. If I understand correctly, creating `n1` would require me to do this. The beauty of matlab's `end` is that this is not needed.

Comment: @bumblebee Not clear about the issue.  If it is a data.table, can you create the 'n1' insside the `data.table?

Comment: No, because it depends on the group. Have added example to the question.

Comment: Works amazingly. I was unaware of the `{...}` option inside `data.table`.

Comment: @bumblebee When you have multiple statements, it can be used

Comment: Understood (thanks!). I think the "Here, we assume n as .N" in your answer could be removed, correct?